# /usr/bin/env: php: No such file or directory with AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

When I deploy a Symfony application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, in a PHP environment (PHP 8.1 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.4.1), the following error appears with Composer:

```
----------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-engine.log
----------------------------------------
[...]
Executing script cache:clear [OK]
Executing script assets:install public [OK]
Executing script requirements-checker [KO]
 [KO]
Script requirements-checker returned with error code 127
!!  /usr/bin/env: php: No such file or directory
!!  
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-install-cmd
```

But when I connect to SSH, the command `composer install` works correctly:

```
cd /var/app/staging/
sudo su -- webapp -c "/usr/local/composer.phar install"
```

```
Executing script cache:clear [OK]
Executing script assets:install public [OK]
Executing script requirements-checker [OK]
```

**vendor/symfony/requirements-checker/bin/requirements-checker**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

include('requirements-checker.php');
```

I don't understand why AWS Elastic Beanstalk don't know "#!/usr/bin/env php" while deploying?

Can you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: What does `which env` give you?

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden `which env` (ec2-user user) returns "/usr/bin/env" and `sudo su -- webapp -c "which env"` returns "/bin/env" (webapp user)

Comment: Because the user who runs this script doesn't have a PATH environment variable or the path to php is not included.

Comment: @shingo it's the root user who deploy. I check `/usr/bin/env` and `php` commands from deployment and it works perfectly. And PATH = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin. I don't understand why it's not working.

Comment: /var/log/eb-engine.log
--
```2022/09/07 14:18:46.489404 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Install composer dependencies]. Stop running the command. Error: installing composer dependencies failed with error: Command /bin/sh -c composer.phar install --no-ansi --no-interaction  failed with error exit status 127. Stderr:Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
As there is no 'unzip' nor '7z' command installed zip files are being unpacked using the PHP zip extension.```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by skipping Composer scripts execution with:

**.ebextensions/01_php.config**

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini:
    composer_options: --no-scripts
```

Then, I run `composer install` again but with scripts execution:

**.ebextensions/02_app.config**

```
[...]
05_composer_install:
    command: |
      runuser -u webapp -- \
      composer.phar install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
```